# what's the wrong that i fell in with stone.scissors&paper game?

Tags: java

My code results in an exception .. can you help me spot my problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random; 
class apples {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner SPS = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose:\tstone,paper or scissors");
    SPS.hasNext();

    Random rand = new Random(2);

    int scissors = rand.nextInt(0);
    int stone = rand.nextInt(1);
    int paper = rand.nextInt(2);

    System.out.println((SPS.hasNext("scissors")||SPS.hasNext("stone")||SPS.hasNext("paper"))? null:"go play away from here");

    if(rand.nextInt() == 0 && SPS.hasNext("scissors")){
        System.out.println("scissors");
        System.out.println("You tie");

    }else if(rand.nextInt() == 0 && SPS.hasNext("stone")){

        System.out.println("scissors");
        System.out.println("You lose");

    }else if(rand.nextInt() == 0 && SPS.hasNext("paper")){

        System.out.println("scissors");
        System.out.println("You won");


    }else if(rand.nextInt() == 1 && SPS.hasNext("stone")){
        System.out.println("stone");
        System.out.println("You tie");

    }else if(rand.nextInt() == 1 && SPS.hasNext("scissors")){

        System.out.println("stone");
        System.out.println("You won");

    }else if(rand.nextInt() == 1 && SPS.hasNext("paper")){

        System.out.println("stone");
        System.out.println("You lose");

    }else if(rand.nextInt() == 2 && SPS.hasNext("paper")){
        System.out.println("paper");
        System.out.println("You tie");

    }else if(rand.nextInt() == 2 && SPS.hasNext("stone")){

        System.out.println("paper");
        System.out.println("You won");

    }else if(rand.nextInt() == 2 && SPS.hasNext("scissors"))

        System.out.println("paper");
        System.out.println("You lose");  
    }
}
```

and the result

```
Choose: stone,paper or scissors
stone
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at stone.paper.scissors.apples.main(apples.java:20)
```

Comment: In what way is "stone" an `int`?

Comment: `int scissors = rand.nextInt(0);
int stone = rand.nextInt(1);
int paper = rand.nextInt(2);` this is so wrong.

Comment: 0 happens to be not positive

Comment: Suggest you consider making an "evaluation" function rather than the list if statements. (makes code a bit cleaner).  BTW the error should give you the line where the error occur

Answer (score 2):

Well, your problem is here:

```
int scissors = rand.nextInt(0);
```

because, as said in the exception, 0 is not positive.

What you wanted to do is:

```
int scissors = 0;
int stone = 1;
int paper = 2;
```

and use the variables after when you are comparing:

```
if (!SPS.hasNext("(scissors|stone|paper)")) {
    System.out.println("go play away from here");
} else {

    int randomChoice = rand.nextInt(3);
    String userChoice = SPS.next();

    if(randomChoice == scissors && userChoice.equals("scissors")){
        System.out.println("scissors");
        System.out.println("You tie");
    }else if(randomChoice == scissors && userChoice.equals("stone")){
        System.out.println("scissors");
        System.out.println("You lose");
    }else if(randomChoice == scissors && userChoice.equals("paper")){
        System.out.println("scissors");
        System.out.println("You won");
    }else if(randomChoice == stone && userChoice.equals("stone")){
        System.out.println("stone");
        System.out.println("You tie");
    }else if(randomChoice == stone && userChoice.equals("scissors")){
        System.out.println("stone");
        System.out.println("You won");
    }else if(randomChoice == stone && userChoice.equals("paper")){
        System.out.println("stone");
        System.out.println("You lose");
    }else if(randomChoice == paper && userChoice.equals("paper")){
        System.out.println("paper");
        System.out.println("You tie");
    }else if(randomChoice == paper && userChoice.equals("stone")){
        System.out.println("paper");
        System.out.println("You won");
    }else if(randomChoice == paper && userChoice.equals("scissors")) {
        System.out.println("paper");
        System.out.println("You lose");
    }
}
```

Note: I also corrected:

- your incorrect use of `rand`
- your incorrect use of the `Scanner`
- your missing brackets for the last `else if`.